# Parsing json in kusto query

Tags: azure

How can I extract individual values from a JSON using KUSTO query.

I want to be able to read the value for SourceSystemId, Message and project these values.  I also want to use date in the following JSON as a filter. And project only those records where date greater than a date supplied as an external parameter.

```
{{
  "Status": 2,
  "SourceSystemId": "4",
  "RequisitionId": null,
  "Errors": [
    {
      "Code": "8002",
      "Message": "some message",
      "FieldName": "VendorNumber",
      "PartNumber": null
    },
    {
      "Code": "8003",
      "Message": "",
      "FieldName": "PartNumber",
      "PartNumber": ""
    }
  ],
  "SuppName": "SomeSupp",
 "Date":"22/2/2017"
}}
```

Answer (score 20):

Let's assume you have a table named `T`, with a column named `MyString`, which stores your JSON values and is typed as `string` (such a table is defined below for the example).

1. You'll first need to invoke `parse_json()` on your column (unless it's already typed as `dynamic` and not as `string`, in which case you can skip this step).
2. Then you can access the `Date` property in your JSON value and use `todatetime()` to cast it to type `datetime`.
3. Afterwards, you can filter by your external parameter (`dateTimeLowerBound` in the example below).
4. Lastly - you can `project` the relevant properties you're interested in (`Message` is in the first element in the `Errors` array, and `SourceSystemId`), and you can cast them to their expected types (e.g. `long` and `string` using `tolong()` and `tostring()` respectively).

Here's the example:

```
let dateTimeLowerBound = datetime(2017-01-21);
let T = datatable(MyString:string) // this table is just for the example
[
'{"Status": 2, "SourceSystemId": "4", "RequisitionId": null, "Errors": [ { "Code": "8002", "Message": "some message", "FieldName": "VendorNumber", "PartNumber": null }, { "Code": "8003", "Message": "", "FieldName": "PartNumber", "PartNumber": "" } ], "SuppName": "SomeSupp", "Date":"2017-02-22"}'
];
T 
| project MyJson = parse_json(MyString)
| where todatetime(MyJson.Date) > dateTimeLowerBound
| project SourceSystemId = tolong(MyJson.SourceSystemId), Message = tostring(MyJson.Errors[0].Message)
```

The output of this example should be a table with 2 columns, named `SourceSystemId` and `Message`, of types `long` and `string`, and with the values `4` an `some message`, respectively.

Comment: suppose he had an array of object with the same properties, how can you deal with that  ? I posted a SO question about this here  : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746111/how-to-transform-a-json-array-of-objects-to-a-kusto-table

Comment: I've replied to that question

Answer (score 1):

Its is simple when you want to parse JSON that is in column and want to have where clause on JSON properties -

```
        tablename 
        | extend prop= parse_json(jsonColumn) 
        | where prop.description == 'My Description' 
        | sort by nameCoumn desc | take 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try |extend Status = extractjson("$.",toString([column]))