# KQL - Why and when do I need the print command with bag_unpack() or dynamic?

Tags: kql

I know the print command outputs a scalar... but why do I need the print command here before bag_unpack, what's it doing?

```
let JsonDynamic = todynamic('{"hello": 1337, "world": ["wibble","wobble","wubble"]}');
print x = JsonDynamic
| evaluate bag_unpack(x)
| mv-expand world
```

or, in this stackoverflow answer, why use print with dynamic???
[How to transform a JSON array of objects to a Kusto table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746111/how-to-transform-a-json-array-of-objects-to-a-kusto-table)

I'm just trying to understand... thank you!!

Sorry this is so vague...I'm trying to understand why I need the print command for this to work?

This doesn't work...

```
let JsonDynamic = todynamic('{"hello": 1337, "world": ["wibble","wobble","wubble"]}');
| evaluate bag_unpack(JsonDynamic)
| mv-expand world
```

but JsonDynamic is a dictionary

```
let JsonDynamic = todynamic('{"hello": 1337, "world": ["wibble","wobble","wubble"]}');
print gettype(JsonDynamic)
```

This does work but x is still a dictionary?

```
let JsonDynamic = todynamic('{"hello": 1337, "world": ["wibble","wobble","wubble"]}');
print x = JsonDynamic
| project gettype(x)
```

They both seem to be dictionaries, but why the does the print command make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I know the print command outputs a scalar*

It doesn't. it outputs a table with single row, with one or more columns (depending on how many scalar expressions you provide it with)

> *why do I need the print command here before `bag_unpack`, what's it doing?*

in your query, the `print` operator takes the scalar expression you pass into it - `JsonDynamic` - and emplaces it in a table with a single row and a single column - `x`. the `bag_unpack` plugin operates on rows in a specific column in a table - thus, you can't simply use it on a scalar value.

> *I'm just trying to understand*

It's not clear what the problem you're trying to solve is. The query you included is valid and works.