# Parsing nested JSON data within a Kusto column

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

After parsing the JSON data in a column within my Kusto Cluster using parse_json, I'm noticing there is still more data in JSON format nested within the resulting projected value. I need to access that information and make every piece of the JSON data its own column.

I've attempted to follow the answer from this SO post ([Parsing json in kusto query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122574/parsing-json-in-kusto-query)) but haven't been successful in getting the syntax correct.

```
myTable 
| project 
Time, 
myColumnParsedJSON = parse_json(column) 
| project myColumnParsedNestedJSON = parse_json(myColumnParsedJSON.nestedJSONDataKey)
```

I expect the results to be projected columns, each named as each of the keys, with their respective values displayed in one row record.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

please see the note at the bottom of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) doc:

> It is somewhat common to have a JSON string describing a property bag in which one of the "slots" is another JSON string. In such cases, it is not only necessary to invoke `parse_json` twice, but also to make sure that in the second call, `tostring` will be used. Otherwise, the second call to `parse_json` will simply pass-on the input to the output as-is, because its declared type is `dynamic`

once you're able to get `parse_json` to properly have your payload parsed, you could use the `bag_unpack` plugin ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin)) in order to achieve this requirement you mentioned:

> I expect the results to be projected columns, each named as each of the keys, with their respective values displayed in one row record.