# kusto function to parse json which is number

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

i could not able to parse the below json value , I tried with parse_json() and todynamic() ,I m getting the result column values to be empty

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHaO8.png)

Comment: it would be helpful if you could include the input data and query as text, instead of as (or in addition to) an image

Comment: you may also want to check if your question isn't already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57403973/7861807

Comment: Thank you @YoniLeibowitz , but I m still getting empty value for my result. Below is my query


app('usl-exepipe-ai-dev').['vsubram1'] 
| extend 
log = parse_json(message).artifactResult.Log
| extend log_json = parse_json(log)
| extend
    stdout_code = tostring(parse_json(log_json)[0]["code"])
    | project stdout_code

Comment: and the data? can you paste that as a string in your original question?

Comment: i don't think anyone except for you will have access to your resource. and the data set you've provided is too bulky. how about a minimal example, without all those `\r`s and `\n`? to make sure it's exactly like in your environment?

Comment: Thank you @YoniLeibowitz.  I have updated data to have only one row of message column where I m trying to parse 'Log' which has two set of data in it

Comment: I could able to parse it with todynamic function
| extend log_json = todynamic(log)
| extend
    stdout_code = todynamic(log_json)[0]["code"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is that your payload includes an internal invalid JSON payload.
it is possible to "fix" it using the query language (see usages of `replace()` in the example below), however it'd be best if you can write a valid JSON payload to begin with.

try running this:

```
print s = @'{"pipelineId":"63dfc1f6-5a43-5bca-bffe-6a36a435e19d","vmId":"9252382a-814f-4d02-9b1b-305db4caa208/usl-exepipe-dev/westus/usl-exepipe-lab-dev/asuvp306563","artifactResult":{"Id":"execution-job-2","SourceName":"USL Repository","ArtifactName":"install-lcu","Status":"Succeeded","Parameters":null,"Log":"[{\"code\":\"ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded\",\"level\":\"Info\",\"displayStatus\":\"Provisioning succeeded\",\"message\":\"2020-06-02T14:33:04.711Z | I | Starting artifact ''install-lcu''\r\n2020-06-02T14:33:04.867Z | I | Starting Installation\r\n2020-06-02T14:33:04.899Z | I | C:\\USL\\LCU\\4556803.msu Exists.\r\n2020-06-02T14:33:04.914Z | I | Starting installation process ''C:\\USL\\LCU\\4556803.msu /quiet /norestart''\r\n2020-06-02T14:43:14.169Z | I | Process completed with exit code ''3010''\r\n2020-06-02T14:43:14.200Z | I | Need to restart computer after hotfix 4556803 installation\r\n2020-06-02T14:43:14.200Z | I | Finished Installation\r\n2020-06-02T14:43:14.200Z | I | Artifact ''install-lcu'' succeeded\r\n\",\"time\":null},{\"code\":\"ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded\",\"level\":\"Info\",\"displayStatus\":\"Provisioning succeeded\",\"message\":\"\",\"time\":null}]","DeploymentLog":null,"StartTime":"2020-06-02T14:32:40.9882134Z","ExecutionTime":"00:11:21.2468597","BSODCount":0},"attempt":1,"instanceId":"a301aaa0c2394e76832867bfeec04b5d:0","parentInstanceId":"78d0b036a5c548ecaafc5e47dcc76ee4:2","eventName":"Artifact Result"}'
| mv-expand log = parse_json(replace("\r\n", " ", replace(@"\\", @"\\\\", tostring(parse_json(tostring(parse_json(s).artifactResult)).Log))))
| project log.code, log.level, log.displayStatus, log.message
```

Comment: Thank You @YoniLeibowitz